# C++ new operator. Creating a new instance

Tags: c++, class, new-operator

I'm having some trouble creating an object in C++. I create a class called Instruction, and I am trying to create a new instance, but I get compiler errors.

Class code:

```
class Instruction{

  protected:
    string name;
    int value;

  public:
    Instruction(string _name, int _value);
    ~Instruction();
    void setName(string _name);
    void setValue(int _value);
    string getName();
    int getValue();
    virtual void execute();
};



//constructor
inline Instruction::Instruction(string _name, int _value){
    name = _name;
    value = _value;
}
//destructor
inline Instruction::~Instruction(){
    //name = "";
    //value = 0;
}
inline void Instruction::setName(string _name){
     name = _name;
}

inline void Instruction::setValue(int _value){
    value = _value;
}

inline string Instruction::getName(){
       return name;
}

int Instruction::getValue(){
    return value;
}
inline void Instruction::execute(){
    cout << "still have to implement";
}
```

This is how I try to create a new object:

```
Instruction* inst;
inst = new Instruction("instruction33", 33);
```

I get the following compiler errors:

```
functions.h:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator new(unsigned int, std::string&, int&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.3/new:95: note: candidates are: void* operator new(size_t)
/usr/include/c++/4.3/new:99: note:                 void* operator new(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)
/usr/include/c++/4.3/new:105: note:                 void* operator new(size_t, void*)
```

You guys are correct. The error comes from this line of code:

```
instList.push_back(inst);
```

where instList is created like this:

```
list <Instruction> instList;  //#include <list> is in the file
```

Comment: I added where the problem was in the code. It happens when I try to add the instruction to a list of instructions.

Comment: Are you compiling with `g++`? I tried compiling this code with `gcc` and I got similar errors.

Comment: I changed the like to list <Instruction*> instList; 
it compiles fine now.  thanks

Comment: Nooooo. You should change it back to a list of instructions. __AND__ you should not by dynamically creating the instruction in the first place. I bet you don't have any of the delets you require.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inst` is a pointer to an Instruction object and `instList` is a list of Instruction objects. So when you try `instList.push_back(inst)` it doesn't work (it expects a real object not the pointer to it). You should instead have `instList.push_back(*inst)`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you would be better of not dynamically creating the Instruction.

```
list <Instruction> instList;

instList.push_back(Instruction("instruction33", 33));
```

Notice there is no need to use new.
If you use new you should be deleting the pointer.
That adds a whole level of complexity that you are not ready for.

Comment: @Martin: Wouldn't this also depend on the scope? For example, if that was done in a function, even if instList is passed back to the main program, the individual Instruction objects will no longer exist, right? since it went out of scope of the function. 
@unknown: But yes, if this will be used only in the scope where it is declared, you should do the above. Other wise using new is okay.

Comment: @aip: Sorry No. The standard containers actually take a copy of the object they pass in. Thus the object in the list is alive as long as the list.

Answer (score 0):

actually, it looks like your error message doesn't have anything to do with the code you pasted in your OP.  I had a very good response ready to go about not passing const char * as a std::string& parameter, but that doesn't look like it's your issue.  What you have posted isn't enough to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you pasted, the error from the message says to check functions.h on line 70.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
instList.push_back(inst);
```

try this:

```
instList.push_back(*inst);
```

You're trying to put a pointer to an Instruction into a list of Instructions.

Comment: If you store a copy of the instance anyway, there is no point in dynamically allocating the original. It just wastes time (dynamic allocation is not cheap) and you must remember to delete the instance right away.